# Reason behind this segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, trigonometry, coredump

This is my function for calculating the inverse sine of a number. It results in segmentation fault for values between 0.51-0.8:

```
double my_asin(double x)
{
    double sum = x;
    if(x < -1.0 || x > 1.0)
    {
        /* error handling */
    }
    else if(x < -0.5)
    {
        sum = -0.5*PI + my_asin(my_sqrt(1-my_pow(x,2))); // SIG_SEGV
        return sum;
    }
    else if(x > 0.5)
    {
        sum = 0.5*PI - my_asin(my_sqrt(1-my_pow(x,2))); // SIG_SEGV
        return sum;
    }

    /* variable initialization */

    while(my_abs(b - a) > EPSILON2)
    {
        /*code*/
    }
    /* return result */
}
```

GDB and valgrind both tell me the error occurs in the function my_pow, which does exactly what you think it does so there's no need to post it here. Can you please take a look and point me in the right direction? Thanks so much.

Comment: If the error occurs in my_pow, you need to fix what you think is broken. No need to post it here.

Comment: Wait... Both GDB and valgrind and saying the error is in my_pow, so what I think it does is cause a SegFault. Thus there is every reason to post it here.

Comment: According to interjay's answer lower on the page, the problem was NOT in my_pow. That's why I posted it here. It just carried on to my_pow where the error triggered. But my_pow did not cause the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose x is `sqrt(2)/2` (about 0.707). Your function recursively calls itself with the parameter `sqrt(1-x*x)`, which is equal to `x`. This will lead to a stack overflow due to infinite recursion.

The same will happen for other values of `x` around that value.

Comment: Thanks, I put this part out of my_asin function and put it in it's own function, so there's no recursion. Thanks for your time and help.